# Reading syslog output on a Mac

Tags: macos, syslog

I have a program that was written for linux and I am trying to build and run it on my MacOS 10.5 machine. The program builds and runs without problem, however it makes many calls to syslog. I know that syslogd is running on my mac, however I can't seem to find where my syslog calls are output to.

The syslog calls are of the form

```
syslog (LOG_WARNING, "Log message");
```

Any idea where I might find my log output?

Answer (score 75):

`/var/log/system.log`

You can monitor it easily using `tail -f /var/log/system.log`

See also the "logger" (`man logger`) and "syslog" (`man syslog`).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in `/var/log/system.log` in newer macOS versions. I can only see them with Console.app

Comment: On newer macOS versions, you'll find the syslog at `/private/var/log/system.log`.

Answer (score 61):

You should probably use the Console.app to view logfiles. It's purdy.

Select your device on the left and filter messages on the right:

[image]

Comment: Um, Console.app automatically shows `system.log`, and other log files.

Comment: What's Purdy ??

Comment: @Pacerier I believe in this case, "purdy" is meant to be a humorous pronunciation of the word "pretty".

Comment: Make senses. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe interesting to note: Apple was using a real `syslogd` in the past but meanwhile all of this has switched to ASL (Apple System Log). The `syslog` command is still available, but it will only access this one log. If you want to access all log messages of ASL across all log files configured, use the `log` command.

E.g. the following shows all log messages produced by Safari within the last two days (be patient, can take a while):

```
log show --predicate 'process == "Safari"' --last 2d
```

See `man log` for all the actions you can perform, all the parameters it knows and what attributes you can filter for.

Answer (score 14):

When in doubt, there's always `man syslog`.

You can find your messages in `/var/log/syslog`; my machine is set up out of the box to only include high level messages so you may need to have your settings.

You can also read the messages through *syslog(1)*, or create a test message with a command like

```
$ syslog -s -l INFO "Hello, world."
```

use a severity of P ("panic") and you'll get an exciting message on your console immediately.

Comment: Doesn't it requires sudo ?

Comment: Not on a mac.  It's not like the panic meassage actually causes a panic:

Last login: Mon Jan 14 22:41:57 on console
499 $ syslog -s -l P "Goodbye cruel world"
                                                                               
Broadcast Message from root@Clarke.local                                       
        (no tty) at 23:57 MST...                                               
                                                                               
Goodbye cruel world

Comment: I find I cannot see messages come up in console, or in the /var/log/system.log, unless I use sudo, or I specify WARN or higher.

Answer (score 11):

Mac OS X implements [a superset of syslog's functionality](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-01-19/next-week-apple-system-logger). All of syslog is there, but as part of ASL.

Console, mentioned by Matthew Schinckel in his answer, is the GUI on ASL. It'll show you any messages that exist in the database, as fetched by queries listed in the sidebar. There are two queries by default; one only shows messages sent with the Console facility (as used by `NSLog`, among other things), whereas the other shows *all* log messages. Check the all-messages query; you'll probably find your message there.

That “all” does come with an asterisk. If you look in /etc/asl.conf, you'll see this line:

```
# save everything from emergency to notice
? [<= Level notice] store
```

Fortunately, in your case, the message will pass this check, since warning outranks (is a lesser number than) notice.

Answer (score 5):

If you need complex `syslog` analysis (navigation hour by hour in terminal, regexp, comparing in real time w\ other files or even running SQL over `syslog`) [lnav](https://github.com/tstack/lnav) would seamlessly provide it for you.

Installation:

```sh
brew install lnav
```

Usage:

```sh
lnav /var/log/system.log
```

UI itself:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on Charlie's answer, I would like to add that you should take a look at the manpage of `syslog.conf(5)` and also take a peek at the file `/etc/syslog.conf` (which is where the syslog configuration is defined by default and also, as I see it, on OS X 10.5.x).

Answer (score 0):

Check for a call to `openlog` somewhere in the program. After a call to `openlog`, `syslog` will save its output to that log file instead of the default location.

Answer (score 0):

#### Big Sur

Unfortunately, non of the stated answers worked for me.

##### What Worked for me:

The *system mail* accessed using the `mail` program from the terminal had all the `/usr/sbin/cron` logs in emails.